# MVC .NET Core 2.0 - _Layout static files do not load for action methods of a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, layout, asp.net-core-2.0

I started a new project in VS 2017 and created a ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application (Model View Controller). Then I've changed the conent of the `_Layout.cshtml` to the interface I want to use (included `@Renderbody` etc.) and included all the static content it requires in the `wwwroot` and save and <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> and the layout shows with all the correct formatting and functionality. No problem so far:

[image: CTRL + F5 and the _Layout shows fine]

However from this point forward none of the static content files of the `_Layout` shows in any other view. So for example if I visit any of the following URLS:

```
http://localhost:52786/home/
http://localhost:52786/home/index
http://localhost:52786/home/about
http://localhost:52786/home/contact
```

I see this:

[image: The static content do not load for _Layout]

`Startup.cs` already has `app.UseStaticFiles()` in `Configure()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like you may have your HTML body content in the wrong place. With ASP.NET MVC &ASP.NET Core MVC, the HTML for each page is served up from the /Views directory (by the Home controller by default), not from the /wwwroot, and it is C# HTML (.cshtml) just like the _Layout.cshtml file. Things like images, static javascript etc. are what's typically located in the /wwwroot directory as these are the parts of your website that are client side instead of server-side.

Try replicating your index, about and contact HTML content as .cshtml files under the /Views/Home directory, replacing whatever's there in the template, except for `@{ViewData["Title"] = "Home";}` located at the top. The layout template should then serve these as the body content (where `@renderbody`... is in _Layout.cshtml).

If this still doesn't work I'll need a bit more info about what you've changed from the default template. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you James for your response. I figured it out and it's actually a noob mistake which I'm posting so that other new developers don't get caught in it.

When you want to reference the content in the wwwroot folder if you reference them without "~/" before the name of the directory it works for the _Layout page which fooled me to think it should work for other parts of the application but you should include "~/" before the folder names explicitly otherwise the static files will be un reachable.